# Codeigniter session doesn't work?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a website based on Codeigniter which works fine. I had to clone this site with database to an another host. I copied the database and all files. My problem is: the session doesn't work on the new site. (I recognized it at the login). The same code works on the old host, but everything is exactly the same.
Does somebody have any idea? Is it a codeigniter configuration issue?
Thanks

Comment: Do you save the session in the database?

Comment: Yes I do. I checked the session table and it always generate a new line in the table, so I think that's the problem but I don't know why?

Comment: Please post your `$config` variables related to sessions.

Comment: Check if the session cookie is actually created, by default is named ci_session. And also did the domain changed?

Answer (score 0):

Check your **application/config.php**
especially these lines:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']  = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

Also: please delete your cookie-history
(if you're using Firefox: CTRL-SHIFT-DELETE)

Alternatively you could use (shameless self-plug) [codeigniter-native-session](https://github.com/atomicon/codeigniter-native-session)
I too had a bit to much problems with the built-in session engine.
It basically mimics the Codeigniter session class so just drop in these files into your application folder and code doesn't needs any modification. (and you'll be using PHP-native-sessions)

Hope it helps.